# Is typeorm's take impossible to remove duplicates in join? (Excluding Group By)

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I want to turn this query into typeorm. I tried to use take(10), but it behaves differently than I intended.

`SELECT * FROM ( select * from Board b  limit 10 ) as b left join Comment c on b.id = c.boardId`

I want to set a limit on a board basis. Regardless of the number of comments. However, if you use take, boardID is duplicated, and if you use groupBy, only one comment is output. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

What I don't quite get is if you're trying to get and array of comments or boards. If what you're looking for are boards, you can do something like the following:

```js
const boards = await entityManager.find(Board, {
    take: 10,
    relations: { comments: true }
})
```

Otherwise, you *can* use that same query, and do some post-transformation:

```js
const comments = boards.reduce((comms, board) => {
    return [...comms, ...board.comments];
    // OR, if you need the board reference inside each comment:
    // const { comments, ...boardWithoutComments } = board; // this is to avoid circular references
    // return [...comms, ...board.comments.map(com => ({ ...com, board: boardWithoutComments }))]
}, []);
```

The last alternative I can think of right now is to run the query as-is, with queryBuilder:

```js
const comments = await entityManager.createQueryBuilder(Comment, "com")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("com.board", "board")
    .where("board.id IN (SELECT id FROM board LIMIT 10)")
    .getMany();
```

You might want to specify and order clause in the boards sub-query, and maybe re-write it as a second, inner queryBuilder in order to use an argument for the limit